# Updating 980K records efficiently where row has a max value in a group

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm struggling to update 980,000 records in the database in a reasonable time.

I have to set value of NextLp to 'NULL' in rows where PriceID is equal to max of a group (grouped by ProductID).

To visualize, here's my example:

```
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| ProductID | PriceID | NextLp | Set NextLp to NULL? |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| APPLE     | 1       | -      |                     |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| APPLE     | 2       | -      |                     |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| APPLE     | 3       | -      | Yes                 |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| PEAR      | 1       | -      |                     |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| PEAR      | 2       | -      | Yes                 |
+-----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

I've tried various methods, but all of them took atleast 15 seconds to update 100 records.. and there's 979,100 more to go - so my methods were definitely not viable.

I appreciate any help.

The version is MS SQL 2016

Comment: Do you have triggers? Do you have concurrent queries on the same table? Do you have your database on full recovery mode? You have indexes on the columns you are querying? Please add as much info as you can, including the actual update statement.

Comment: @EzLo can't answer that. The server is rather remote and I only have access through a console I can run queries on.

Althought, other update query on the same amount of records runs in under 50 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something along this?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ProductID VARCHAR(100),PriceID INT,NextLp VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('APPLE',1,'-')
,('APPLE',2,'-')
,('APPLE',3,'-')
,('PEAR ',1,'-')
,('PEAR ',2,'-');

WITH UpdatableCTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY PriceID DESC) AS Nr
    FROM @tbl 
)
UPDATE UpdatableCTE SET NextLp=NULL
WHERE Nr=1;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

You can use an updateable CTE first to place numbers to your rows, then to update the ones you target.

### UPDATE

The result

```
ProductID   PriceID NextLp
APPLE       1       -
APPLE       2       -
APPLE       3       NULL
PEAR        1       -
PEAR        2       NULL
```

With my example above two rows were set to `NULL`. Both rows are the *highest PriceID* within their group...

`ROW_NUMBER()` is [a *window function*](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/). The [`OVER()`-clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows for `PARTITION BY` to create groups within the set, while the `ORDER BY` will sort the group, in this case by the `PriceID` in descending order. This will bind a `1` to each row, where the `PriceID` is the highest within a group of `ProductID`.

**Hint:** You can use `SELECT * FROM UpdatableCTE` instead of the `UPDATE` statement. This will show you the numbered rows and allows to check the numbering.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change NextLp at all.
Changing ORDER BY to ProductID and PARTITION BY to PriceID sets all of NextLp to NULL thought.

Comment: @JCode Sorry, might be I got something wrong... See my update

Comment: My bad, it didn't occur me that doing SELECT TOP(100) might not yield all results in the database, hidding the one with NULL as a result.

Thank you very much and good day to you sir.